# Why mysql restored only a part of records from the dump?

Tags: mysql

I have a following problem. I had to move a database from one mysql server to another. I used mysqldump to make a dump from the first server. Copied it to the second, and used mysql to restore it in an empty database.

Everything seems to be fine, but one of the tables (or maybe more, but one is for sure) was not restored completetely. It had about 150000 records in original database, but only 27000 after restore. Why would that happen?

Now, the second sever has a database installed from scracth, no additional adjustments were made to the my.ini. Maybe the problem is in the large size of this particular table? How to fix that in my.ini, so it would accept the large database dump?

UPDATE: I found the answer - the problem was in max_allowed_packet. I increased the size, and the restore process went fine.

Comment: How are you checking the number of records ?  Are you getting any errors ?  Also, what database type are you using, is it InnoDB, because the official MySQL 5.1 documentation acknowledges that InnoDB does not give accurate statistics with SHOW TABLE STATUS, if that is what you are using.

Comment: No, I use just select count(*) from ... The database is InnoDB. I think there were some warnings, but it simply stated: N records inserted, where there M warnings, without going into detail

Comment: You need to check the warnings then.

Comment: He does not print the warnings content, he just prints the number of them.